# prove that $P(\min(X,Y,Z)>t \mid X<Y<Z ) = P( \min(X,Y,Z)>t )$ **conditions apply

Tags: probability, random-variables, conditional-probability, exponential-distribution

### **GIVEN**

[image]

Let $A$,$B$ and $C$ be independent poisson processes with arrival rates $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ and $ \lambda_3$ respectively.

Let $X,Y$ and $Z$ are times until the first arrival in processes A,B and C respectively.

$\Rightarrow X,Y $ and $Z$ are independent exponentials with parameters $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ and $ \lambda_3$ respectively.

Also,
$ \min(Y,Z)$ is the time until the first arrival in merged process BC

and
 
$ \min(X,Y,Z)$  is the time until the first arrival in merged process ABC

$\Rightarrow \min(Y,Z)$ and $ \min(X,Y,Z)$ are exponential random variables with parameters $(\lambda_2+\lambda_3)$ and $(\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3)$ respectively

event $X<Y<Z$ occurs when arrivals *in merged process ABC* follow the following order

- the very first arrival comes from process A.
- first arrival from process C, comes after an arrival from process B.

event  $ \min(X,Y,Z)>t $ occurs when there are no arrivals in the merged process ABC until time $t$

two ways to prove $P(X<Y<Z \mid \min(X,Y,Z)>t) = P(X<Y<Z )----(1)$  are as follows:

1. using the memorylessness property of exponential r.v's.
2. using the time independence property of poisson processes.

we were able to use the time independence property of poisson processes(or the memorylessness property of exponential r.v's) to prove ---(1) because when we condition on $ \min(X,Y,Z)>t $, we are essentially told some information about the past. But the event $X<Y<Z$ occurs in the future.

---

### TO PROVE

I have been asked to prove $P( \min(X,Y,Z)>t \mid X<Y<Z ) = P( \min(X,Y,Z)>t )----(2)$ 
without converting the LHS of (2) to LHS of (1) .
 
*any hints to avoid the following computation (that involves integrals)?*

---

### WHAT I HAVE TRIED

$P( \min(X,Y,Z)>t \mid X<Y<Z ) = P( X>t \mid X<Y<Z ) = \int_t^{\infty}f_{X \mid X<Y<Z}(x)dx$

but I have been unable to simplify the pdf $f_{X \mid X<Y<Z}(x)$

---

### ADDITIONAL QUESTION

how to simplify the pdf $f_{X \mid X<Y<Z}(x)$?

---

ps:
i know the following formulas

[image] and[image]

Comment: Are you trying to prove that
$$
\mathbb P(X<Y<Z\mid \min(X,Y,Z)>t) = \mathbb P(X<Y<Z)
$$
or
$$
\mathbb P(\min(X,Y,Z)>t\mid X<Y<Z) = \mathbb P(\min(X,Y,Z)>t)?
$$
It is not clear from your question.

Comment: i am trying to prove the latter *without* using the prior. i'll edit the question. thanks!

Comment: Hint: $\min(X,Y,Z)$ is exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3$.

Comment: i've edited the question once more, to clearly distinguish between what i know and what i don't

Comment: Has the hint helped you? If not, consider asking for more help by asking math1000 directly (using the @ to address them) or starting a bounty.